# The Webbrowser in WPF can't display page unless mouse moving on

Tags: wpf, browser

The Webbrowser in WPF can't display page unless mouse moving on.

This bug can't reproduce in my demo project, and I don't know how to fix it.
I tried:

- call WindowsFormsHost.UpdateLayout. (Failed)
- call WindowsFormsHost's child, a WebBrowser control. call WebBrowser.Update or WebBrowser.Refresh. (Failed)
- call WindowsFormsHost.InvalidateVisual() (Failed)

Is there other solution?

---

I even simulated mouse moving on like this:

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(winAdHoster.Handle);
ATGTestInput.Input.MoveToAndClick(element);
```

this failed again.

Answer (score 0):

I have tree questions:

- Does this happens after reboot?
- Do you have `AllowsTransparency="True"` for the main window?
- What OS do you have?

Comment: Does this happens after reboot? (YES, ALWAYS)
Do you have AllowsTransparency="True" for the main window? (YES, BUT WebBrowser on other window, because WebBrowser control will always disapperence on a transparency='true' window)
What OS do you have? (XP and Win7)

Answer (score 0):

In order to simulate actual mouse events, you can use following function throgh PInvoke, its system api to simulate mouse events this will work better then AutomationElement.

[SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this bug via:

1. moved init WebBrowser code to a method, which is the last method in Window_Loaded event.
2. using BeginInvoke and Thread.Sleep(500) before init WebBrowsers.

We tested it on WinXp and Win7, it works well.